# Using measures to divide rows in one table by rows in another

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple data model in place: 2 local authority education budget datasets, joined with a simple reference table of local authority names. Works great for visualisations.

Now I need to divide specific rows in one table, by specific rows in the other. For example: Table 1 has the budget expenditure for Secondary Schools in Cardiff. I need to divide that row of data by Table 2's row containing the pupil numbers for secondary school phase in Cardiff. This would give me a per pupil spend for secondary school phase in Cardiff.

Any help with this would be great. DAX is not my preferred language, so my apologies if this is achingly simple.

Producing a Power BI report for colleagues to use in analysing Education budgets.

This would give me a per pupil spend for secondary school phase in Cardiff.

Comment: If your tables have a relationship between columns, then `RELATED` might do the trick. Otherwise, you can probably use `LOOKUPVALUE` to get what you need.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you had some sample data and desired ouput to work from.

Comment: Thank @Alexis Olson. Will have a go with those two functions. If not, I'll come back with some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOOKUPVALUE worked with DIVIDE. Here's the generalised formula that I now use to carry this out:

```
LOOKUP_Measure =
DIVIDE (
    'Numerator_DT'[Numerator_Values],
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        'Denominator_DT'[Denominator_Values],
        'Denominator_DT'[Concatenated Key], 'Numerator_DT'[Concatenated_Key]
    )
)
```

Note that I had to create a concatenated key in this example in order to access the most granular level of the data table. In this example, I needed to concatenate a local authority code, educational phase and financial year, output column were permutations on the following: 592 - P - 201516.

Hope that helps someone.